# Merging/namespacing PM2 apps

Tags: node.js, pm2

There is PM2 configuration, `/home/foo/someconfig.json`

```
{
    "apps": [
        {
            "name": "foo-main",
            "script": "./index.js",
        },
        {
            "name": "foo-bar",
            "script": "./bar.js"
        },
        {
            "name": "foo-baz",
            "script": "./baz.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

Most of the time I want to refer to all of the apps under current namespace, e.g.

```
pm2 restart foo
```

instead of doing

```
pm2 restart foo-main foo-bar foo-baz
```

Bash brace extension cannot be used because apps may run in Windows.

Doing `pm2 restart /home/foo/someconfig.json` isn't a good option, because it takes some time to figure out config file path, it may differ between projects and even change its location.

Can `foo-*` apps be merged into single `foo` app or be referred altogether in another reasonable way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pm2` supports regex's since 2.4.0, e.g.

```
pm2 restart /^foo-/
```

If using with the `start` command, remember to provide the eco system file as first parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I was searching for the term 'pm2 application wildcard' found no success, thought this might help future googlers.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that `pm2` itself doesn't support wildcard-based restart, but it is not complex to make a simple script to do it using [pm2 programmatic API](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-api/).

Here is a working script that demonstrates the idea:

```
var pm2 = require('pm2');

pm2.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(2);
  }

  pm2.list(function(err, processDescriptionList) {
    if (err) throw err;
    for (var idx in processDescriptionList) {
      var name = processDescriptionList[idx]['name'];
      console.log(name);
      if (name.startsWith('foo')) {
        pm2.restart(name, function(err, proc) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log('Restarted: ');
          console.log(proc);
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

To make it fully functional, it is also necessary to pass `foo` as command-line argument (now it is hard-coded) and handle exit (now it works, but doesn't exit on finish).

Here is the [full code example](https://github.com/serebrov/so-questions/tree/master/nodejs-pm2-wildcard-restart), including small sample apps and config.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good use of pm2 API. I wish there was a conventional way to do this, since global `pm2` command with no extra hassle has its benefits.